# I was trying to install Tkinter

Tags: python

[python shell tkinter command error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4pf5.png)
this error encountered while i was trying to install Tkinter using command

Comment: You're trying to run a linux command in a Windows shell. Get the Windows version and try again.

Comment: If you installed Python with the installer on Windows, you should already have the `tkinter` module installed.

Answer (score 2):

sudo apt-get install is Linux command, not Python. You need to execute it in the shell/terminal.

Comment: `sudo` is not a native Windows command, which is not what it looks like the OP has…

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter does not need any tyoe of installation, all you need to do to use it is simply type in:
`import tkinter`